# Limit resultset to just the first column's value in the first row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

I have a dynamic SQL situation where a query coming in could be a SQL command, or it could be a stored procedure. I need to be able to grab the first value in the top left corner of the result set. I've figured out a way to do this for SQL, but not for stored procedures.

For SQL scripts, I use `sp_describe_first_result_set` to determine how many columns there are and generate a matching script with null columns to union against like so:

```
select null as C1, null as C2 where 1=0 union all select 'hello', 'world'
```

which makes it pretty simple to get just the `top 1 C1`.

With stored procedures, however, I can't use this same technique because sometimes the stored procedures have different return paths that result in incompatible results for `sp_describe_first_result_set`. I can't insert the resultset into a temporary table because I don't know how many or what the columns will be.

Comment: What about using `select into` with `openrowset` as [described here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1551/using-sql-servers-openrowset-to-break-the-rules/)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, No, because of the restriction that the stored procedures sometimes have incompatible results (eg, sometimes the SP returns several columns, but if you provide a parameter of @onlyCount=1 then the result would just be one column with the record count in it). Besides all of that, I'd have to pass connection string information which feels bad (this script will live in hundreds of databases, each used by a separate company).